# Algorithm or Test Method to generate test case for Keno game

Tags: algorithm, testing, random, combinations, probability

Keno Game rules: Keno is a lottery-like game which generates random combination of number ranging from 1 to 80 with the size of 20. Player may choose a number game to play (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15). The payout depends on the number game and number of matches.

I understand the difficulties of generating a complete test case to cover all possible combination not to mention the possibility of matching the random game result. Therefore, I initially applied the Random Combination testing method but later found out it is hard to achieve high coverage of all possible cases (roughly about 10%). By now, I have come across Pure Random Combinatorial, CATS, AETG, K-combination but none is ideal for Keno game.

For now, the inputs are `num_game_size`, `numSelected[num_game_size]`. Meanwhile, the outputs are `result[20]`, `matchedNum[]`, `matched_num_size`, `payout`. Of course, there are more inputs: `continuous_game_toplay_size`, `bet_amount`.

I'm looking forward for any suggestion on any testing method or algorithm that has high coverage on pure random and large combination test case if executed for a month or two. My objective is to test combination of selected numbers and their payout for each different number of matches when the result is pure random generated. For instance:

```
/* Assume the result is pure random generated */
/* Match 0 */
num_game_size = 2
numSelected[2] = {1,72}
result[20] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}
matchedNum[] = {}
matched_num_size = 0
payout = 0

/* Match 1 */
num_game_size = 2
numSelected[2] = {1,72}
result[20] = {1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}
matchedNum[] = {1}
matched_num_size = 1
payout = 1

/* Match 2 */
num_game_size = 2
numSelected[2] = {1,72}
result[20] = {1,72,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}
matchedNum[] = {1,72}
matched_num_size = 2
payout = 5
```

The total possibility will be `C(80,2) * C(80,20) = 3160 * 3535316142212174320 = 1.117159900939047e+19`. Meaning for each combination of number with the size of two within range of 1 to 80, there are C(80,20) possible results. It will probably takes few years to cover all possibility (including 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15 number game) when the result is pure random generated (quantum RNG).

Ps: Most test method I found only consider either random or combination problem and require a tremendous amount of time to complete test case generation. I'm trying to create any program to help me in winning the Keno game IRL.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing exactly? Do you want to 'test' your implementation, or you want to simulate a game of keno to compare resulting probabilities to calculated ones?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I have a Keno game ready to be tested. I'm looking for a test method or any algorithm that is able to generate test cases with high coverage on all the possible outcome of the game.

Comment: he probabilities of matching k numbers are listed on the wikipedia page for Keno. From this, you can compute the expected payoff from playing any of the numbers games without simulation.